# if (fi->Attributes & System::IO::FileAttributes::Normal),Having bitwise problem

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, c++-cli, clr

I not sure is CLI support or incomplete.

Having bitwise problem.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    FileInfo ^fi = gcnew FileInfo("c:\\test.txt");
    if (fi->Attributes & System::IO::FileAttributes::Normal)
        Console::WriteLine("Attrib : normal");
    else
        Console::WriteLine("Not normal file");


    return 0;
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2451   conditional expression of type 'System::IO::FileAttributes' is illegal  ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\jack\source\repos\consoleapplication193\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp    14
Error (active)  E0711   expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Jack\source\repos\ConsoleApplication193\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp    11

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes?view=net-7.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-attributes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a bitwise operation as such –`&` is overloaded for `System::IO::FileAttributes` and produces a `System::IO::FileAttributes`, which is not convertible to `bool`.

You need the condition

```
(fi->Attributes & System::IO::FileAttributes::Normal) == System::IO::FileAttributes::Normal
```

but since you're `using namespace System::IO`, you can cut that monstrosity down to

```
(fi->Attributes & FileAttributes::Normal) == FileAttributes::Normal
```